# Nodejs - child_process execSync with java outputting to console and not buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, child-process

I have an execSync call as follows:

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
...
console.log('Checking Java version')
let java_version= execSync('java -version').toString();
console.log('Java version:', java_version);
console.log('java_version is empty string:', java_version=="");
if(!java_version)
  throw Error('Java version was empty or null.');
```

If I check the logs, I see:

```
Checking Java version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
Java version:
java_version is empty string: true
[ERROR] 'Java version was empty or null.'
```

The problem isn't that the command isnt being run, its that the output of the command isnt being returned as a buffer as it's supposed to. It's going straight to Node's stdout. Any other command seems to properly output its stdout to Node. I tried changing the command to `execSync('echo "testing\n a different command\n\n"').toString();` and everything works as expected and the output is returned properly. I've also tried subshelling it with `execSync('$(java -version)').toString()` and  `execSync('echo $(java -version)').toString()` but no luck.

What's going on here?

If it helps, it's on ubuntu 19:10

EDIT:
I solved it by running `execSync('echo $(java -version 2>&1)').tostring()` but I would still like to know why and how it was being piped to the nodejs stdout and bypassing execSync's buffer. Thanks.

Comment: `java -version` writes to stderr, not stdout

Answer (score 0):

Because execSync('java -version') has return nothing. You should use it only when you want to execute a script without return anything. To get return something you have to use a callback like this.

```
execSync('my.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
if (err) {
 console.error(err);
 return;
}
console.log(stdout);
});
```

if you did not read the following documentation, please read it.Then you will understand a lot of concept to run a child process.
[enter link description here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

the docs say that it returns the stdout of the command. I've always used it like this for any other command, it's only Java that's caused this issue. My guess is Java is hardcoded to output to the stdout of the system and not back to its calling process. Even in bash if you try to echo $(java -version) > testFile   then cat testFile it returns nothing

Comment: It's writing to stderr instead of stdout (there's no such thing as "stdout of the system"). You can see the same problem with anything else that writes to stderr, such as `dd count=0` or `ls doesnotexist` or `echo Hello >&2`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Why would Java default to writing to stderr for a perfectly valid command that functions as intended....

Answer (score 0):

```
let java_version= execSync('java -version 2>&1').toString();
```

tested in linux

Comment: Please explain your solution.